# Carbon Aggregator re-aggregating metric

Tags: graphite

I have the following aggregation rule:

`abc.prod.ALL.<service>.<metric>.count (60)   = sum abc.local.*.<service>.<<metric>>.count`
Given metrics like:

```
abc.prod.host1.aservice.ametric.count
abc.prod.host2.aservice.ametric.count
```

I would expect them to be aggregated to

`abc.prod.ALL.aservice.ametric.count`

But that metric is never created.  In aggregator logs, I see

> Allocating new metric buffer for abc.prod.ALL.aservice.ametric.count

but it's not created.  If I add a layer to the generated metric like:

`abc.prod.extralayer.ALL.<service>.<metric>.count (60)   = sum abc.local.*.<service>.<<metric>>.count`

then we seem to get a recursive explosion of created metrics like:

```
abc.prod.extralayer.ALL.aservice.ametric.count
abc.prod.extralayer.ALL.ALL.aservice.ametric.count
abc.prod.extralayer.ALL.ALL.ALL.aservice.ametric.count
abc.prod.extralayer.ALL.ALL.ALL.ALL.aservice.ametric.count
```

Which led me to believe that the generated metric is then aggregated again...

I added a logging line to `AggregationProcessor.process`:

```
  else:
    log.clients("Found aggregate " + aggregate_metric + " for " + metric)
    aggregate_metrics.add(aggregate_metric)
```

And then tried with my original, desired rule.. and I eventually started to see, loglines like:

> Found aggregate abc.prod.ALL.aservice.ametric.count for abc.prod.ALL.aservice.ametric.count

It matched itself as if it was a new incoming metric... Why is it being fed back into the aggregator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to have been a bug.  It was not in older version but was in master at the time of my question.

If you are seeing this behaviour, follow the issue on GitHub:
https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/issues/560
https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/issues/455

There is no point in continuing the question here on SO.

Note: I am using the older version, 0.9.15 and not seeing the problem - so I recommend this until it is confirmed to not be resolved in master.